# How to filter traffic coming to particular page from other page?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I've got page A linking to page B. There are also other pages linking to B.
How can I see traffic that is coming to page B *only* from page A?

I can somehow do it via Behavior flow:

> Behavior > Behavior flow > [Right click on anything] Explore traffic
>   through here > [Click edit icon] Define a page group > [Right click]
>   Group details > [Dropdown] Incoming traffic

But how do I do it in normal reports? Is there any way to filter out only the traffic coming from a particular page?

Comment: I guess you are talking about Google Analytics, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a Custom Report.

Select the metrics and dimensions that you want to report on and then under the "Filters" section you would "Include" "Referral Path" "Exact (Exactly matching)" "A (or the path of the page you wish to filter traffic from".

You might also add a second filter for Page "B" if you only want to see the traffic to this page.